# Getting updates to a page as soon a they are posted to the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs, database

I am currently trying to get updates from the database as soon as it is added. Currently, I am doing this by refreshing the content in a div every second. (The short refresh type is required for the application.) However, this is massively impactful on server load and I am looking into a more elegant solution. After much web searching, the only information I can find is how to do it via the method I am currently using.

Having looked on competitor (established sites in a new market), they do not use the refresh method I have just mentioned and so I know that it is possible, but I'm stuck there.

I'd essentially like to add new rows to a table (on the same page, not embedded if possible) every time a new row is added to the database.

Could anybody provide any guidance?

Comment: As you've seen, interval polling puts a lot of load on the server,especially as the number of active users increases. A much better solution would be to use websockets.

Comment: Try pubnub, using their scripts you can send messages through there system and have those received by any browser connected to your 'channel'

Comment: what if you stored a last modified datetime (LMD) in the db that was amended on each db update. Then when you first pull the data in - store the LMD in  local storage. In your cycle- you do a query that only gets the LMD from the DB and only if if does not match the stored LMD - pull the entire content into the div. Still a server load - but better than pulling the entire div every time,

Comment: Like the first guy mentioned you are looking for websockets... I have tried using it and there is no real simple solution or examples out there... goodluck.

Comment: If websockets is not an option for you then maybe consider using a cache server in front of your web servers. I've had very good results with Varnish. You could put a Varnish in front of your web server and simply purge the relevant cache whenever the DB is updated. Varnish servers should be able to handle thousands of hits per second...

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. It has given me a lot of direction. The only examples I can find are 'chat' applications, which all seem to use MongoDB rather than MySql. Is it bad practice to have both in use on the same website or could I go for one of these solutions?

Comment: It seems you're searching [Server-sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or [WebSocket](http://www.websocket.org/).